# Multiple NIntegral with singularity

Tags: numerical-integration, singularity

I need to compute the following integral `FF[0]`. When evaluating `FF[0]` *Mathematica* simply takes too much time. The problem may arise due to singularity in the limit 1. I tried specifing different options of `NIntegrate`, but no luck. Any suggestions why the computation of `FF[0]` stalls ? I am working on the code below:

```
FF[z_] := NIntegrate[f1[v] NIntegrate[f4[u], {u, 1, v}], {v, 1, z}];
```

It involves the functions below:

```
f1[z_] := z^2/((1 + z + z^2) Sqrt[1 - z^3]);

f2[z_] := (-2 - 3 z^2 + 5 z^3 + 9/2 z^2 Sqrt[1 - z^3] 
           NIntegrate[f1[u], {u, 1, z}])/(-1 + z^3);

f3[z_] := (z^2 (8 - 12 z - 2 z^3 + 6 z^4 + 3 Sqrt[1 - z^3] (-4 + z^3) 
           NIntegrate[f1[u], {u, 1, z}]))/(-1 + z^3)^2;

f4[z_] := 1/((1 + z + z^2) Sqrt[1 - z^3]) (16 (-1 + z) (1 + z + z^2) Sqrt[1 - z^3] + 
           6 (-4 - 4 z - 4 z^2 + z^3 + z^4 + z^5) NIntegrate[f1[u], {u, 1, z}] + 
           Sqrt[1 - z^3] (-4 (-4 + 2 z + 2 z^2 + 3 z^3) +
           4 (1 + z + z^2) NIntegrate[f2[v], {v, 1, z}] -
           3 (1 + z + z^2) NIntegrate[f3[s], {s, 1, z}]));
```

Comment: There are simple mistakes - For example, `NIntegrate` takes only numerical values as bounds, but you are trying to pass an analytic bound. You should read the documentation centre carefully.

Comment: In FF, you do not write NIntegrate twice, that is the wrong syntax. Again, look at the documentation.

Comment: Thank you. To Sektor: But I do not need the analytic result. I just need FF[0].

Comment: To Tom Dickens: If ff1 etc. are simple functions, we can get FF[0] easily, for instance ff1[z_]:=z;ff4[z_]:=z; FF[0]= 0.125`. Why do you say we can not write NIntegrate twice?

Comment: The syntax is NIntegrate[ f1[v] f4[u]  ,{v,1,z},{u,1,v}] . Read the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is using `NumericQ` - see [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037)

Another problem is how many times `NIntegrate` is being called.  To do the 2D integral in `FF`, `f4` will be called tens of thousands of times.  Computing `f4` in turns does three 1D integrations, which will call `f1`, `f2`, `f3` several hundred times. And there's still one more layer:  `f2` and `f3` integrate `f1`.

Finally, to estimate the integral:  For singularities of this type -- essentially one over a square root -- there are several possible tricks to eliminate or integrate out the singularity: substitution, Taylor series expansion, or integration by parts.  I'll use a partial Taylor series expansion.

Another trick is to use `NDSolve` instead of `NIntegrate`.  My experience shows that usually `NIntegrate` will be more accurate for less effort, but in this case, the nested integrations can be performed much more rapidly with a single call to `NDSolve`.

My guess is that this integral is zero or nearly zero.  Tickling the settings makes the result dance around zero.  See examples below.  The problem is too complicated to tempt me to investigate further.

---

Suppose the integrand is of the form $f(z)/\sqrt{1-z^3}$.
Let $p(x)$ be the Taylor polynomial of $f(x)$ centered at $x=1$:
$$p(x) = f(1) + f'(1)\,(z-1) + {1 \over 2!}\, f''(1)\,(z-1)^2 +
            \cdots + {1 \over n!}\, f^{(n)}(1) \,(z-1)^n$$

We can write the function in the form
$${f(x) \over \sqrt{1-z^3}} = 
  {1 \over \sqrt{1-z^3}} p(x) - {1 \over \sqrt{1-z^3}} \left(f(x) - p(x) \right)$$ 
The first term may be integrated exactly. In the second, the remainder $f(x)-p(x)$ vanishes at $x=1$ with order $n+1$ and the factor $\sqrt{1-z}$ in the denominator may be eliminated.

#### Code

The function `calcFF0[approxorder]` splits the integrand into two parts as above, one using the Taylor polynomial of order `approxorder` for the rational function factor and the other being the remainder.  The first is called `f1partialsum` and its integral `intpartialsum`.  The remainder is called `f1tail` and its integral is represented by `inttail`.  The symbols `f2i, f3i, f4i` represent the integrals of `f2, f3, f4`.  The OP's integrals are translated into the differential equations in `diffeqs0`; these are then processed to replace `f1` by the partial sum and tail.

```
ClearAll[calcFF0, f1, FF];
f1[z_?NumericQ] := z^2/((1 + z + z^2) Sqrt[1 - z^3]);
FF[z_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[f1[v] f4int[v], {v, 1, z}, Exclusions -> {v == 1}, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 50];

calcFF0`timings = {};
calcFF0[approxorder_Integer] /; approxorder >= 1 := 
 Block[{diffeqs, ivals, fli, zf1i, f2i, f3i, f4i, f1partialsum, 
   f1tail, intpartialsum, inttail f1sqrt, zf1i0, zf1i1, dzf1i0, dzf1i1, 
   diffeqs0, z},
  calcFF0`timings = {};

  {f1partialsum, f1tail} = 
   1/( Sqrt[1 - z] Sqrt[1 + z + z^2]) {#, z^2/(1 + z + z^2)  - #} &@
     Normal@Series[z^2/(1 + z + z^2), {z, 1, approxorder}] // Simplify;
  AppendTo[calcFF0`timings, 
   "intpartialsum" -> 
    First@AbsoluteTiming[
      intpartialsum = 
        Assuming[0 < z < 1, 
         Integrate[f1partialsum /. z -> u, {u, 1, z}]];]
   ];
  Off[Limit::ztest, Limit::ztest1];
  f1sqrt = 
   Limit[(D[intpartialsum, z] - f1tail)/D[Sqrt[1 - z^3], z], z -> 1];
  zf1i0 = 
   Limit[(intpartialsum + 
       NIntegrate[f1tail /. z -> u, {u, 1, 0}, AccuracyGoal -> 60, 
        PrecisionGoal -> 60, WorkingPrecision -> 100] - 
       f1sqrt Sqrt[1 - z^3])/(Sqrt[1 - z^3] (1 - z)), z -> 0];
  zf1i1 = 
   Limit[(intpartialsum - f1sqrt Sqrt[1 - z^3])/(Sqrt[
       1 - z^3] (1 - z)), z -> 1];
  dzf1i0 = 
   Limit[D[(intpartialsum + inttail[z] - f1sqrt Sqrt[1 - z^3])/(
      Sqrt[1 - z^3] (1 - z)), z] /. {inttail[z] -> zf1i0, 
      inttail'[z] -> f1tail}, z -> 0];
  dzf1i1 = 
   Limit[D[(intpartialsum + inttail[z] - f1sqrt Sqrt[1 - z^3])/(
      Sqrt[1 - z^3] (1 - z)), z] /. {inttail[z] -> 0, inttail'[z] -> f1tail}, 
    z -> 1];
  On[Limit::ztest, Limit::ztest1];
  ivals = {
    f4i[1] == 0,
    f3i[1] == 0,
    f2i[1] == 0,
    inttail[1] == 0,
    zf1i[1] == zf1i1
    };
  diffeqs0 = {
    f4i'[z] == 
     1/((1 + z + z^2) Sqrt[1 - z^3]) (16 (-1 + z) (1 + z + z^2) Sqrt[
          1 - z^3] + 6 (-4 - 4 z - 4 z^2 + z^3 + z^4 + z^5) f1i[z] + 
        Sqrt[1 - z^3] (-4 (-4 + 2 z + 2 z^2 + 3 z^3) + 
           4 (1 + z + z^2) f2i[z] - 3 (1 + z + z^2) f3i[z])),
    f3i'[z] == (z^2 (8 - 12 z - 2 z^3 + 6 z^4 + 
          3 Sqrt[1 - z^3] (-4 + z^3) f1i[z]))/(-1 + z^3)^2,
    f2i'[z] == (-2 - 3 z^2 + 5 z^3 + 
        9/2 z^2 Sqrt[1 - z^3] f1i[z])/(-1 + z^3),
    inttail'[z] == f1tail,
    zf1i'[z] == 
     PiecewiseExpand@
      If[z == 0, dzf1i0, 
       If[z == 1, dzf1i1, 
        D[(intpartialsum + inttail[z] - f1sqrt Sqrt[1 - z^3])/(
          Sqrt[1 - z^3] (1 - z)), z] /. inttail'[z] -> f1tail]]
    };
  diffeqs = 
   Simplify@
      Collect[# // Simplify, {zf1i[z]}] & /@ (diffeqs0 /. {f1i[z] -> 
        Sqrt[1 - z^3] ((1 - z) zf1i[z] + f1sqrt)});
  AppendTo[calcFF0`timings, 
   "f4int" -> 
    First@AbsoluteTiming[{f4int} = f4i /. NDSolve[{diffeqs, ivals},
          {f4i},
          {z, 0, 1},
          MaxSteps -> 25000, AccuracyGoal -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 20, 
          WorkingPrecision -> 50, Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching"}];]
   ];
  (AppendTo[calcFF0`timings, "FF[0]" -> First@#]; Last@#) &@
   AbsoluteTiming@FF[0]
  ]
```

#### Examples

Calculation is pretty quick up to order 2. Around order 5 the expressions become cumbersome.

```
Table[calcFF0[i], {i, 10}]
(*
  {-1.3244026180261123588915843875040816322466525948705*10^-19, 
    3.0015066202265498858065794938827534572730220506990*10^-20, 
    3.0015066202265498858065794938827534572730220506990*10^-20, 
    1.8703459094818216335723220477167003403290466171147*10^-20, 
    1.6186535958160423926232560464349953531508440283849*10^-20, 
    1.1735419707791214544755429836505597298579609121478*10^-20, 
    4.7867151751302942415829600894502557404630460424603*10^-21,
   -3.6094172859114470277845844574784350053347977553360*10^-22,
   -3.6094172859114470277845844574784350053347977553360*10^-22,
   -1.0996197631289901595882055987785067444207300272497*10^-22}
*)

calcFF0[20]
(*
  -3.5412378870111975729395101114276072893513118648442*10^-23
*)
```

Comment: Great answer！I am sorry that I have not seen this answer two weeks ago. Thank you so much.